# How to make a CMake library target depends on arbitrary files?

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm making a binary resource wrapping tool with CMake, it is implemented by inline assembly `.incbin` directive. Briefly it works in this way:

1. CMake script obtains a list of input files, and generate a source file (let's call it `rcs_bundle.cpp`) by `configure_file` command. The generated source file mostly contains a large inline assembly that includes all input files by `.incbin`:

```
__asm__(
   ".const_data\n"
   ".globl _data1_BEGIN\n"
   ".balign 16\n"
   "_data1_BEGIN:\n"
   ".incbin \"/full/path/to/data1\"\n"
   // omit data1 size generation lines that are not important in this topic

   ".globl _data2_BEGIN\n"
   ".balign 16\n"
   "_data2_BEGIN:\n"
   ".incbin \"/full/path/to/data2\"\n"
   // omit data2 size generation lines that are not important in this topic

   // and many more resources ......
   ".text\n");
```

2. A static library is generated simply like `add_library(rcs_lib STATIC rcs_bundle.cpp)`, and it is used in further parts of this product.

Here the problem comes. Ideally `rcs_lib` should be automatically recompiled when any data file is changed. However, the CMake target does not know its depencency on those data files, because `.incbin` is not recognized by any dependency walker. And CMake does not provide a way to manually specify file-level dependencies, as `add_dependencies` only works on targets.

I have also tried to create a fake target and specify dependency like this:

```
add_custom_target(rcs_lib_deps DEPENDS /full/path/to/data1 /full/path/to/data2)
add_dependencies(rcs_lib rcs_lib_deps)
```

But it just won't work at all.

So is there any way to add file dependencies in CMake? As this approach would be only used in Mac for me, is there any Clang compiler directives to manually specify dependency in C++ source?

Comment: Does _linking_ of the library depend on the files? Or _compiling_ rcs_bundle.cpp depends on the files? `rcs_lib should be automatically recompiled` So `rsc_lib` is a library, it is linked together from object files coming from compiled  cpp files. So which one depends on the files?

Comment: @KamilCuk the compilation to object depends on these files, exactly as in the first part of your posted answer.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand incbin , producing the object file from rcs_bundle.cpp depends on the files. In such case, you would:

```
set_source_files_properties(rcs_bundle.cpp PROPERTIES OBJECT_DEPENDS
     /full/path/to/data1
     /full/path/to/data2
 )
```

In contrast, if *linking* rsc_lib depends on the files (for example with a custom linking script), then you would set a property on the library:

```
 set_target_properties(rsc_lib PROPERTIES LINK_DEPENDS
     /full/path/to/data1
     /full/path/to/data2
 )
```